# How can I create a layer for each unique field item in a shapefile using Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, layers, definition-query, split-by-attribute

```
#Introduction and imports
import arcpy, string
from arcpy import env

#User Inputs: layer, field name, output workspace (optional)

strTargetLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
strFieldName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
strSuffix = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
strOutputWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

TargetLayer = arcpy.mp.Layer(strTargetLayer)
TargetLayerDQ = TargetLayer.definitionQuery
Field = arcpy.ListFields(strTargetLayer, strFieldName)[0]
env.workspace = strOutputWorkspace
env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
df = df.listMaps("Drill Plan Map-Main")[0]
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(strTargetLayer)
lstValues = []

#Creating set(lstValues)
for row in cursor:
    lstValues.append(row.getValue(strFieldName))
lstValueSet = sorted(set(lstValues), reverse = True)
del lstValues

#Creating layers in map
arcpy.AddMessage("Creating layers in map...")
LyrList = []

for i in lstValueSet:
    try:
        if TargetLayerDQ !="":
            if i is None:
                ilyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TargetLayer, "NULL" + strSuffix).getOutput(0)
                ilyr.definitionQuery = TargetLayerDQ + ' and ' + "\""+Field.name+"\"" +' is NULL'
            elif Field.type == 'String':
                ilyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TargetLayer, i + strSuffix).getOutput(0)
                ilyr.definitionQuery = TargetLayerDQ + ' and ' + "\""+Field.name+"\"" +' = ' + "\'"+ i +"\'"
            else:
                ilyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TargetLayer, str(i) + strSuffix).getOutput(0)
                ilyr.definitionQuery = TargetLayerDQ + ' and ' + "\""+Field.name+"\"" +' = ' + str(i)
            arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df,TargetLayer,ilyr,"AFTER")
        else:
            if i is None:
                ilyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TargetLayer, "NULL" + strSuffix).getOutput(0)
                ilyr.definitionQuery = "\""+Field.name+"\"" +' is NULL'
            elif Field.type == 'String':
                ilyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TargetLayer, i + strSuffix).getOutput(0)
                ilyr.definitionQuery = "\""+Field.name+"\"" +' = ' + "\'"+ i +"\'"
            else:
                ilyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TargetLayer, str(i) + strSuffix).getOutput(0)
                ilyr.definitionQuery = "\""+Field.name+"\"" +' = ' + str(i)
            arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df,TargetLayer,ilyr,"AFTER")
        LyrList.append(ilyr.name)
    except:
        if arcpy.GetMessages(2) != "":
            arcpy.AddMessage("**FAILED TO EXECUTE FOR " + str(i) + "**")
            arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
        pass
#Saving layers to folder
if strOutputWorkspace != "":
    arcpy.AddMessage("Saving layers in target location...")
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        if lyr.name in LyrList:
            arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyr.name,lyr.name,"ABSOLUTE")
```

Comment: On brief reading the code looks fine to me, what problem are you encountering? Are you getting any error messages? Can you limit your question to only a few lines of code please.

Comment: Have you looked into the 'Split By Attributes' tool?  See:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm

Comment: I am getting an error on line 16 TargetLayer = arcpy.mp.Layer (strTargerLayer)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mp'

I have looked into 'Split By Attributes' but it is not exactly what I'm trying to do here.  I want just new layers with definition query's not new features.

Comment: Your error suggests to me that you are not using the ArcGIS Pro version of arcpy, which includes the arcpy.mp module.  If you're using ArcMap you'll have to rewrite it to use the arcpy.mapping module.